# Swap values round in a column - R

Tags: r, dataframe

How do I swap one value with another in a column within a dataframe?

For example swap the 2's and 4's around in df1 to give df2:

```
df1 <- as.data.frame(col1 = c(1,2,1,4))
df2 <- as.data.frame(col1 = c(1,4,1,2))
```

Comment: ifelse(df1==2, 4, df1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution using `replace` in base R:

```
df2 <- data.frame(col1 = replace(df1$col1, c(4,2), c(2,4)))
```

**Output**

```
  col1
1    1
2    4
3    1
4    2
```

Answer (score 1):

We can try using `case_when` from the `dplyr` package for some switch functionality:

```
df2 <- df1
df2$col1 <- case_when(
    df2$col1 == 2 ~ 4,
    df2$col1 == 4 ~ 2,
    TRUE ~ df2$col1
)
df2

  col1
1    1
2    4
3    1
4    2
```

**Data:**

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = c(1,2,1,4))
```

Comment: Thanks this solution worked for me, although I have accepted slava-kohut's solution as it was the simplest :)

Answer (score 1):

you can swap by reassigning the index for that column.

With the dataframe:

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = c("a","b","c","d"))

> df1 
  col1
1    a
2    b
3    c
4    d
```

we can:

```
df1[,1] <- df1[c(1,4,3,2),1]
```

to get

```
> df1 
  col1
1    a
2    d
3    c
4    b
```